# EF Core Sqlite LIKE Unicode comparison

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, unicode, entity-framework-core

We have a Windows .Net Core app using Sqlite and EF Core (latest) that deals with unicode data (non-ascii characters).

As the official Sqlite docs explain (https://www.sqlite.org/matrix/quirks.html) by default unicode case folding is not enabled. That means that e.g. the LIKE operator won't do case-insensitive comparison for non-ascii characters so "ä" will NOT equal "Ä".

The official docs also mention that it's possible to enable this LIKE case-insensitive comparison for unicode by using the ICU extension. I'm having a hard time finding a compiled version of it that's usable on Windows.

So I guess I have several questions:

1. Is there a compiled version of the ICU extension downloadable somewhere?
2. Is there an alternative way of achieving case-insensitive unicode LIKE? I found several potential options but they either didn't work (column collation, global collation etc) or seem clunky/slow (overriding the default LIKE operator and performing a LIKE in code)

Comment: You might also want to test your final outcome for performance after you get it working for correctness. I say might because I am not sure how large the data set is and if you have indexes on the column being filtered. If you apply something like casting or converting to upper case etc most DBMS will not be able to use any index set on that column and I am guessing SqlLite is probably the same.

Answer (score 0):

ICU is a unicode/localization library and not a sqlite extension.

A list of available sqlite extensions can be found here https://www.sqlite.org/src/file/ext/misc, and none of them support unicode search.

In order to get unicode support, you likely will need to [build](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html) sqlite yourself using the `SQLITE_ENABLE_ICU` compile parameter. Make sure that you have ICU installed beforehand so that you can reference and link it during the build process

Comment: I'm afraid this is incorrect: https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact?ci=trunk&filename=ext/icu/README.txt

"The easiest way to compile and use the ICU extension is to build and use it as a dynamically loadable SQLite extension"